# Android java toggle a page with menubutton

Tags: java, android, toggle

I'm looking to create a separate page (layout and subactivity) in my app which you access by clicking the menu button. I want it to toggle in the way that when you click the menu button again you return to the MainActivity and the activity_mail.xml layout.

I'm having a degree of success with this bit of code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    setContentView(R.layout.settings);



    return true;
}
```

This successfully switches to the settings.xml layout. But how do I return to the activity_main.xml layout when the menu button is pressed again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not what the `optionsMenu` is created for but however. There are a lot of possible ways to do that. One possible way to do that would be to create a boolean field variable.

```
private boolean isInMailLayout = true;
[...]
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    if(isInMainLayout){
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        isInMailLayout = false;
    }
    else {
        setContentView(activity_mail.xml);
        isInMailLayout = true;

    }

    return true;
}
```

#### The purpose of the `optionsMenu`:

The optionsMenu should display a Menu in either an [overflow drop down list](http://clickortap.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/overflow.png) (if you use the ActionBar) or in a [grid at the bottom of the phone](http://www.authsmtp.com/images/android-2-2-4.jpg) (if you don't use an ActionBar).

You on the other hand don't want to display a menu, but change the layout. You might want to start a new Activity for this.

Comment: Can you refer me to an explanation of what the optionsMenu is created for or if there's a best practice to acheive this without using the optionsMenu?

Comment: That's excellent. Thanks very much. I've tried putting this code in my MainActiviy and once the button is pressed it seems to get stuck on the "return true" part.

Comment: What do you mean? Did it crash?

Comment: it seemed to just rest on the return true part and not respond to the button press again. Eventually I got my head around activities and KeyEvents and did it this way:

Comment: @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if ( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
         activityName= this.getClass().getSimpleName();
   String MainAct = "MainActivity";
     
   Intent startNewActivityOpen = new Intent(MainActivity.this, settings.class);
   if(activityName.contains(MainAct)){
    startActivity(startNewActivityOpen);
   } 
      else {
    //startActivity(startNewActivityOpen.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
       finish()
    ;
      }
         return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }